# How to disable select dropdown based on "id" or "class" in html

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I have a dropdown, I have a condition like:

```
       <select>
         <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
         <option value="saab">Saab</option>
         <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
         <option value="audi">Audi</option>
       </select>

 {% if user_name == "boby" %}{% endif %}
```

I have to disable the "select" tag, else I have to enable it.

How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `jinja2` but you could do something like this.

```
  <select  {% if your_condition %}disabled{% endif %} >
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
     <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   </select>
```

If the condition is false, then it will not be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Once the page loads you can check the user name and set the dropdown list as desired...

```
<body onload="if(user_name=='boby'){ Your_Select_ID.disabled=true; }">
```